# Binomial Theorem Question $1+(1+x)+(1+x)^2+\dots+(1+x)^n$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

The coefficient of $x^k (0 \le k \le n)$ in the expansion of $E = 1+(1+x)+(1+x)^2+\dots+(1+x)^n$ is

\begin{alignat}{2}
\text{(A)}& \binom{n+1}{k+1} &\qquad \text{(B)}& \binom{n}{k} \\
\text{(C)}& \binom{n+1}{n-k-1} &\qquad \text{(B)}& \binom{n+1}{n-k-1}
\end{alignat}

Please help me or provide an useful hint for the question.

Comment: Sum the geometric series & then use binomial.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.
I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle. For some basic information about writing math,at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559).

Answer (score 3):

Since [hint should be posted as answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10597/290189), I post my hints here.

> \begin{align}\sum_{r = 0}^n (1+x)^r&=\frac{(1+x)^{n+1}-1}{(1+x)-1} \\ &=\frac1x\left[\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n+1}{k}x^k\right] - \frac1x \end{align}